# C - passing allocated pointer and using realloc in separate function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, argument-passing, realloc

I need to find all the prime factors of a number. I have written this code, but when I try to reallocate the pointer array in calculatePrimes function using realloc, gcc gives error that i have not allocated the pointer before using realloc. I know I can pass the double pointer and use malloc inside the calculatePrimes function or, use a single pointer and return the value.

Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calculatePrimes(int max, int** array){
    int size=1, i;
    *array[0]=2;
    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            *array = (int *)realloc(**array, (++size)*sizeof(int));
            *array[size-1]=i;
        }
    }
}

int isPrime(int value){
    int i=2, root = sqrt(value);
    for(;i<root;i++){
        if(value%i==0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


void main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int input = atoi(argv[1]), numPrimes;
    int *primes=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    calculatePrimes(input, &primes);
    numPrimes=sizeof(primes)/sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n", numPrimes);
    free(primes);
}
```

Comment: You should show the exact error, since your re-phrasing ("gcc is giving error that I have not allocated the function before") doesn't make a lot of sense. Functions are not allocated ...

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc or realloc, it can hide certain subtle errors from you.

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect usage of `realloc()`. The correct is below:

```
*array = realloc(*array, (++size)*sizeof(int));
```

When you pass `**array` to `realloc()` you pass the value of the first element of the array that is `int` instead of `int*`.

Note that I've also removed the cast. In C, it's not needed and can hide certain problems you don't want hidden. Specifically, it can give you the wrong function signature for `malloc/realloc` which, if your `int` and `void*` type aren't compatible, can lead to corrupted pointers.

Comment: Please consider [not casting the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).